# Can anyone find where the conflict is and give me a solution for this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, eslint, conflict

Compiled with problems:

ERROR

[eslint] Failed to load config "react-app/jest" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/aurrelkondi/Desktop/MY PROJECT:REACT/PORTFOLIO-REACT/portfolio-app/package.json

Comment: Could you please post the content of package.json?

Comment: I think it works now. I deleted the package.json and installed it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **package.json** version
Probably you need to update the package to make it compatible.
Try:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

If it shows any major update from your current version, then updating the project’s **package.json** file.

run:

```
npm install
```